# How to use Opencart Product Profile?

Tags: opencart

anyone know how to apply Opencart 1.5.6 new feature product profile? which is located in the admin menu - catalog - profile ?

I heard it can be used to break payment into several part, but i don't understand how it really works. Can i use it to let my buyer pay in 50% first then after my product is ready to ship, they pay the rest 50% again with that feature?

Thank You very much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a new feature in OpenCart that could be understood by proper searching and reading of the original documentation.

Comment: @Onstudypurpose, While this may be on-topic for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart, it is definitely not on topic here because StackOverflow only allows "programming" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the documentation and dont forget to enable payment gateway like paypal express

http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Profiles